# How did Jesse end up with the cigarettes in his pocket?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I watched the season 4 ending of *Breaking Bad* and the story is that Huell underhandedly replaced Jesse's cigarettes with an other pack. Jesse desperately looks for the ricin cigarette at the hospital and thus empties out every cigarette.

At this point Walt has the ricin, Saul has the old cigarettes and Jesse think Gus poisoned Brock.

So in this last episode, Jesse is leaving Saul's office, Huell lifts his dope and somehow he ends up with his old pack of cigarettes that used to contain the ricin.

Did Huell put it back? Why in the world would he do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's as simple as this, these are Jesse's cigarettes.

If you notice, he pulls them out of his right-hand side pocket.  He had his weed in his left-hand side pocket.  Huell lifted the weed and *nothing else*.

[image: Left Side]

[image: Right Side]

It is a simple argument of Jesse is a smoker, always having a pack of cigarettes on him.  These particular cigarettes happen to be his favoured brand, therefore having a pack on him in his pocket.

It is not the same pack that Huell lifted the ricin cigarette from.  It merely sparks the train of though that led to Jesse's rage and realization.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks. Jesse should have realised it way before when the doctors said it was not ricin that poisoned Brock, but he was seeing Walt as he is seeing Mike in season 5A and would buy any of what Walt could tell him. But in this episode Jesse finally sees that Walt is 'working him' and as he looks at his cigarettes, the pieces come together. Ive always envisionned the moment that Jesse would find out either that Walt let Jane die or that he poisonned Brock and Aaron Paul sent shivers down my spine during his scene with Saul.